# TypeScript 2.8 unavailable in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use TypeScript **2.8** in my Visual Studio **2019** as my team is using that version of TS. However, when I go to Project properties -> TypeScript Build it says that the version is *unavailable*. I tried installing that specific TS SDK version by using the Visual Studio Installer but it appears to be not in the list there. The only version I am seeing is **3.5**.

[image]

How can I set up VS 2019 so it uses TS 2.8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't have VS2017 installed you can just install the SDK from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258

It says for VS2017 but it is standalone and VS2019 recognises it.

**Update**: Good solution but the link is for TypeScript 3.2 and the original question is for 2.8. **Use this link for 2.8**: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/0/A/70A6AC0E-8934-4396-A43E-445059F430EA/2.8.4-TS-release-dev14update3-20180515.1/TypeScript_SDK.exe **Or open the Details section to see all versions.**

Comment: I will accept this solution as it does not require the user to have VS 2017 installed (i.e. much simpler)

Answer (score 6):

I managed to use TypeScript 2.8 in Visual Studio 2019 by launching Visual Studio 2017, go to the Installer and install the 2.8 SDK from there. Not sure why this is not an option in Visual Studio 2019

[image]

Then, when I launched Visual Studio 2019 it was picked up just fine